# Excel column sum where the condition is in a adjacent column

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel table with the name t that has columns A and B. column A has the values "YES" and "NO" and column B has the category names (lets say I have category c1 c2 c3). How can I count the amount of values YES in each category.

```
A    B
YES  c1
YES  c2
YES  c1
NO   c3
NO   c3
NO   c2
YES  c1
YES  c1
```

In this example for category c1 the value is 3, for c2 it is 1 and for c3 it is 0.

Comment: Are you bound to Excel or would you be open to work in Google Sheets instead? Their script editor makes it quite easy to solve problems like this.

Comment: Use COUNTIFS().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:B8,"c1",A1:A8,"yes")
```

Change `c1` to whichever category you want.

Comment: didn't hnow COUNTIFS existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the pivot table. 
[image]

[image]